# Trouble With Conditional Logic in PHP

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have created an advanced custom field that allows editors to add an image and title to be displayed in a Bootstrap 3 carousel. I am having trouble with the conditional logic for the image field. The script we are using is designed to use the image added in the advanced custom field and if there is no image in the advanced custom field it uses the post's featured image. The same is true for the title. If a title is entered in the advanced custom field it uses that. If no title is added to the advanced custom field it uses the post title.

The title part is working as expected, but the image part does not work; it always uses the featured image even when an image is added to the advanced custom field. I suspect there is something wrong with the conditional logic used within the carousel code, but I can not figure out what is wrong. I have posted the script below and would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Thanks in advance for your help.

````
// Based on code originally developed by Ben Blakley. See http://www.charityandbiscuits.com/blog/create-bootstrap-wordpress-carousel-tagscategories-featured-images/
// Custom loop for featured items in Bootstrap Carousel. 
// Slider will show posts in the 'Featured' category

// Exported PHP from Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Creates custom fields which are added to post, page, and event editors.


if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_featured-posts-slides',
        'title' => 'Featured posts slides',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_5270201a54e4a',
                'label' => 'Image',
                'name' => 'carousel-image',
                'type' => 'image',
                'instructions' => 'Upload an image here if you don\'t want to use the Featured Image',
                'save_format' => 'id',
                'preview_size' => 'home-slider',
                'library' => 'all',
            ),
            array (
                'key' => 'field_527020aa54e4b',
                'label' => 'Title',
                'name' => 'carousel-title',
                'type' => 'text',
                'instructions' => 'Put a short title here if you don\'t want the image slider to use the Post/Page Title',
                'default_value' => '',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'prepend' => '',
                'append' => '',
                'formatting' => 'none',
                'maxlength' => 83,
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'post',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 0,
                ),
            ),
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'page',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 1,
                ),
            ),
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'event',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 2,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array (
            'position' => 'side',
            'layout' => 'default',
            'hide_on_screen' => array (
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
    ));
}



//Add a WordPress image size if the slider image size isn't already set in WordPress. 

add_image_size( 'home-slider', '750', '410', true );

//Creates a shortcode so you can just type [carousel] wherever you want the slideshow displayed.

function carousel_shortcode(){

$number = 0; 
$q =  query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post_type' => array ( 'post', 'page','event') ) );

if(have_posts()):
        
    //If no thumbnail or carousel-image exists leave it out of the loop to avoid blank slides.
    //If carousel-image set, use it, otherwise use featured image thumbnail('home-slider).  
    //If carousel-title set, use it as slide title, otherwise use the_title()
?>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
     <?php
      $postIdl = get_the_ID();
      $has_featured_imagel =  has_post_thumbnail( $postIdl );    
      $carousel_imagel = get_field('carousel-image');   
      $carousel_image_urll = $carousel_imagel['url'];
      if($carousel_image_urll != '' || $has_featured_imagel) 
      {
     ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
    <?php } endwhile; ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
     <?php
      $slider_image = '';
      $slider_title = '';
      $postId = get_the_ID();
      $has_featured_image =  has_post_thumbnail( $postId );
      $carousel_title = get_post_meta($postId, 'carousel-title', $single = true);
      $carousel_image = get_field('carousel-image');    
      $carousel_image_url = $carousel_image['url'];
      if($carousel_title != '')
      {
        $slider_title = $carousel_title;
      }
      else
      {
         $slider_title = get_the_title();
      }
       if($carousel_image_url != '')
      {
        $attachment_id = get_field('carousel-image');
$size = 'home-slider'; 
 

        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('carousel-image'), 'home-slider' );
        $url = $thumb['0'];
        $slider_image = '<img src="'.$url.'">';
      }
      else
      {
         $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'home-slider' );
         $url = $thumb['0'];
         $slider_image = '<img src="'.$url.'">';
      }
      if($carousel_image_url != '' || $has_featured_image) 
      {
     ?>   
    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><?php echo $slider_title; ?></h3>
        
      </div></a>
    </div>
    <?php  } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>

  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  
  <a id="left" class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left icon-2x"></i></a>
  <a id="right" class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right icon-2x"></i></a>
</div>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query();
}

add_shortcode('carousel', 'carousel_shortcode');  



//Add js to footer. Change the interval to alter how long the slides display - 4000 equals 4 seconds.
function featured_carousel() { ?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
  $("#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
   $("#myCarousel").carousel({
  interval: 4000
  })
});

</script>
<?php
}
    add_action('wp_footer', 'featured_carousel');```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried dumping the value of `$carousel_image`
For image field to return Array, `return_type` must be set to `array`

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/#field-type%20settings

> ```
> /* (string) Specify the type of value returned by get_field(). Defaults to 'array'.
>   Choices of 'array' (Image Array), 'url' (Image URL) or 'id' (Image ID) */
>   'return_format' => 'array',
> ```

Also what's the use of `save_format` in your code . I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad.